# How to access element of "another" array when using aura:iteration?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I want lightning code similar to this C code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < childs.size(); i++)
{
    if (parents[i] == childs[i])
        cout << parents[i] << " is a parent of " << childs[i] << endl;
}
```

I have two attributes for the array, parents and childs and I pull the correct data. I tried this:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.childs}" var="child" indexVar="index">
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.parents[index] == child}" >
    {!v.parents[index]} is a parent to child <br></br>
    </aura:if>                  
</aura:iteration>
```

I figured the indexVar field would be what I wanted but it doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: In this case you should be using `Map`.

Comment: You logic `v.parents[index] == child` seems to be saying "parent object is child object" not "is a parent to child". Is there a field you should be comparing e.g. `v.parents[index].Id == child.Parent__c`? Using `indexVar` seems reasonable to me..

Comment: you can't use the `indexVar` as part of an evaluated expression, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

> It's simple as below... Just use your child  array again with **aura:iteration** and compare it with parent iteration.

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.parents}" var="parents">
  <aura:iteration items="{!v.childs}" var="childs">
    <aura:if isTrue="{!childs == parents}">
        {!childs}
    </aura:if>
  </aura:iteration>
</aura:iteration>
```